# SQL: Get count of rows for values in another column even when those values do not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a table named 'products' with two columns: name and status.
I would like to get the count of rows in the table with statuses as `Draft`, `Published` and `Rejected`.
This is the query I tried,
`select count(*), status from products where status in ('Draft', 'Published') group by status;`

At the moment the table does not have any row with the status as `Published` or `Rejected`.
So the above query just returns one row with status and `Draft` along with its count

```
 count | status 
-------+--------
    24 | Draft
```

However, I would like to the query result with the other statuses as zero.

```
 count | status 
-------+--------
    24 | Draft
    0  | Published
    0  | Rejected
```

How should I write the query so that I get the results as above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a list of the statuses and a `left join`:

```
select v.status, count(p.status)
from (values ('Draft'), ('Published'), ('Rejected')
     ) v(status) left join
     products p
     on p.status = v.status
group by v.status;
```

Comment: The query had minor syntax issues, but on fixing that works as expected. Not able to update your answer with correct query since SO allows for atleast 6 character changes to edit. But your query needed only two character changes.

Comment: Here is the syntax fixed query
`select v.status, count(c.status)
from (values ('Draft'), ('Published') ,('Rejected')
     ) v(status) left join
     campaigns c
     on c.status = v.status
group by v.status;`